# Updating an object in an array's visibility

Tags: javascript, meteor

My app is a two player game where there's a grid of buttons when the two players enter the game. The object of the game is to press more buttons than your opponent before all of the buttons are gone. The buttons disappear by setting the visibility of the button to hidden. For some reason this isn't working and not throwing any errors to server or client. Here's my method:

```
Server.JS



 hideButton: function(bubble){
    console.log("method works")
    Bubbles.update({_id: this._id}, {$set: {visibility: "hidden"}}) 
  }


This is how the buttons are created

allocateGame = function(userId) {
  var gameWaiting = Games.findOne({players: {$size: 1}, current: true});

  if (!gameWaiting) {
    console.log("creating a new game, none available");
    //Added updated, required to start and finish games.
    Games.update({players: userId}, {$set: {current: false}}, {multi: true});
    var gameId = Games.insert({players: [userId], active: false, finished: false, current: true});
      _.times(64, function(n){
        Bubbles.insert({gameId: gameId});
  });

  } else {
    console.log("connecting with an existing waiting player");
    Games.update({_id: gameWaiting._id}, {$set: {active: true}, $push: {players: userId}});
  }
};
```

The template event:

```
Client.JS


Template.grid.events({
  'click .button': function (event) { 
    var clickedElement = event.target
    console.log(clickedElement)
    Meteor.call('hideButton','clickedElement')
  }
})
```

The button should only be updated for the current game the two players are in. Not all current games. I'm pretty sure I'm targeting the right thing but not hiding the buttons. What am I doing wrong here?
[Deployed project](http://bubblepopper.meteor.com/#) and [My git repo](https://github.com/Yahkob/BubblePopper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a 'stub'. Your `Meteor.call` is received by your method `hideButton`. But this is on the client side, I think? If you added a server side one it could be a fix (if you want the latency compoensation)

This means that it is a 'stub'. The actions that are run in it are virtual and doesn't send anything to the server.

The main reason for something like this is its used for latency compensation: If you have a `hideButton` on the server too, you could use the client side `virtual` one to make it appear as if the Bubble has been updated instantly, even though the server would have not received the message yet.

The fix for this would be to use a function instead.

In addition to this you have a couple of other issues (which would not be there with the fix involving an ordinary javascript function/method, but just to mention them):

- `Meteor.call('hideButton','clickedElement')` - Your parameter `clickedElement` is a string, you should send down the ID of the Bubble here not `clickedElement` or its object (since you cant send DOM elements with Meteor.call
- Your `hideButton` method uses `this._id`, where `this` would not have an `_id` since its scope would be for the method. Hence the reason to pass the `_id` of the Bubble when calling it instead.

Because of these the Update does try a virtual update that you would see only on your browser session, but because `this._id` is null, nothing is updated & no errors are thrown (since its a virtual stub nothing happens on the server either)